React process.env prints all variables correctly, but individual env vars are not accessible
Please note: although this question mentions OIDC I believe this to be a pure JS/React question at heart, and does not require experience with React OIDC to answer!

I have a React app with the following index.jsx:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider } from "react-oidc-context";
import Dashboard from "./users/Dashboard";
import AcceptInvitation from "./users/AcceptInvitation";
import ExpiredToken from "./users/ExpiredToken";
import AboutUs from "./web/AboutUs";
import AccountSettings from "./users/AccountSettings";
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary';
import { keycloakBaseUrl } from './keycloak/KeycloakConstants';

const oidcConfig = {
    authority: keycloakBaseUrl,
    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT,
    redirect_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOK_REDIRECT_URL
};

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <Router>
            <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />
                    <Route path="/accept-invitation" element={<AcceptInvitation />} />
                    <Route path="/account-settings" element={<AccountSettings />} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                    <Route path="/error" element={<ErrorBoundary />} />
                    <Route path="/expired-token" element={<ExpiredToken />} />
                </Routes>
            </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
    </ErrorBoundary>
);

That KeycloakConstants.js looks like:
const KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT = process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT;
const KEYCLOAK_REALM = process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM;
const keycloakBaseUrl = `${KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}`;

console.log("keycloakBaseUrl = " + keycloakBaseUrl);
console.log(process.env);

export { keycloakBaseUrl };

And my .env file looks like:
REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL="http://localhost:3000"
REACT_APP_FULL_NAME=My app
REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT=http://localhost:8080
REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM=myapp-internal-realm
REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT=myapp-ui-client
REACT_APP_KEYCLOK_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000/dashboard
REACT_APP_API_GATEWAY="http://localhost:9200"

When I try going to an authenticated page/route I get an error that indicates my OIDC info isn't being loaded properly:

"Oops... Invalid response Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8, from URL: undefined/realms/undefined/.well-known/openid-configuration"

When I open Developer Tools to view the console log output from my KeycloakConstants.js page I see:
keycloakBaseUrl = undefined/realms/undefined

{NODE_ENV: 'development', PUBLIC_URL: '', WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}
FAST_REFRESH
: 
true
NODE_ENV
: 
"development"
PUBLIC_URL
: 
""
REACT_APP_API_GATEWAY
: 
"http://localhost:9200"
REACT_APP_FULL_NAME
: 
"My app"
WDS_SOCKET_PORT
: 
undefined
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

So process.env is loading just fine, just not my individual KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT and KEYCLOAK_REALM env vars. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? Do I need to add anything at the top of KeycloakConstants.js to get it to load the env vars properly?

Your environment variables need to be prefixed with REACT_APP_ in order for react to use them.
If you don't have access to change them then you need to redefine them in your env file like this
REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT=${KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT}

Which will take the system env variable and make it accessible in react.

Thanks @Devon Ray (+1) I should have posted my .env file, so I just updated my question to contain it. I am already doing this!

If you update the question removing the bugs, it will defeat the purpose of StackOverflow.

No what I'm saying is that my .env file already contained @Devon's suggestions and is behaving as described (not working).

In that case @hotmeatballsoup its because you are using the variables incorrectly, in your KeycloakConstants.js file you are using process.env.KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT instead of process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_HOST_AND_PORT
